# How to convert decimal number to Base58 in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, base-conversion

```
myNumber=$(date +%s) # big number in decimal
myNumberInB58=$(toBase58 $myNumber)

toBase58() {
  # <your answer here>
}
```

What is the most elegant and/or concise way to encode an integer in [**Base58**](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Base58)?

Comment: And what exactly do you consider Base58 to be? A reference link would be useful.

Comment: Done. See http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Base58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another version:

```
# Order-Preserving Base58 (OPB58).
# Also supports negative numbers.
int2b58() {
  # Omit IOlo
  local n="$1" i BASE58=$(echo {0..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..n} {p..z} | tr -d ' ')
  ((n < 0 )) && printf -- '-' && n=$((-n))
  for i in $(echo "obase=58; $n" | bc); do
    printf ${BASE58:$(( 10#$i )):1}
  done; echo
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [bitcoin-bash-tools](https://github.com/grondilu/bitcoin-bash-tools) provide the functions `{en,de}codeBase58`:

```
decodeBase58() {
    echo -n "$1" | sed -e's/^\(1*\).*/\1/' -e's/1/00/g' | tr -d '\n'
    dc -e "$dcr 16o0$(sed 's/./ 58*l&+/g' <<<$1)p" |
    while read n; do echo -n ${n/\\/}; done
}

encodeBase58() {
    echo -n "$1" | sed -e's/^\(\(00\)*\).*/\1/' -e's/00/1/g' | tr -d '\n'
    dc -e "16i ${1^^} [3A ~r d0<x]dsxx +f" |
    while read -r n; do echo -n "${base58[n]}"; done
}
```

Those work with the fields `dcr` and `base58` defined directly above in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
a=( {1..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..z} )
toBase58() {
    # TODO: check that $1 is a valid number
    local nb=$1 b58= fiftyeight=${#a[@]}
    while ((nb)); do
        b58=${a[nb%fiftyeight]}$b58
        ((nb/=fiftyeight))
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$b58"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning bitcoin address leads me to this question, inspired by Elifarley's great answer, this new answer(include *encode* and *decode*) pay more attention to **bitcoin address friendly** and **POSIX-compliant**

```bash
encode58() {
    b58chars=123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz
    numHex=$1

    # remain leading 1 in base58
    prefix=''
    if test "00" == "$(echo -n $numHex | cut -c 1-2)"; then
        prefix=1
    fi

    numHex=$(echo -n $numHex | tr a-z A-Z)
    num58=''
    for charIndex in $(echo "obase=58;ibase=16;$numHex" | bc | tr -d '\n\\'); do
        num58=$num58$(echo -n $b58chars | cut -c $(( 10#$charIndex+1 )))
    done
    echo $prefix$num58
}

b58CharToDicimal() {
    i=0
    for char in $(echo {1..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..z}) ; do
        if test $1 == $char ;then
            echo $i
            return 0
        fi
        i=$(( ${i}+1 ))
    done
    echo 'invalidate base58 char'
    return 1
}

decode58() {
    num58=$1

    # remain leading 00 in hexadecimal
    prefix=''
    if test "1" == "$(echo -n $num58 | cut -c 1)" ; then
        prefix=00
    fi

    exponent=$((${#num58} - 1))
    numDecimal=0
    for char in $(echo $num58 | sed 's/./& /g') ;do
        digit=$(b58CharToDicimal $char)
        numDecimal=$(echo "$digit * 58 ^ $exponent + $numDecimal" | bc)
        exponent=$(($exponent-1))
    done
    numHex=$prefix$(echo "obase=16;$numDecimal" | bc | tr A-Z a-z)
    echo $numHex
}
```

You can check it with the example from [How to create Bitcoin Address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address)

```bash
encode58 00f54a5851e9372b87810a8e60cdd2e7cfd80b6e31c7f18fe8
decode58 1PMycacmJaSqwwJqjawXBErmLsZ7RkXUAs
```